# which factory and which method of that factory to use to send data

Tags: magento2

Basically, I want to send the data taken from "**form**" and send it to database. I know how to get data from the database (using collection factory).

I need to know the procedure to send the data to the database using the factory method, not object manager method.

Comment: Can you please explain more? For which functionality you are trying to save data.

Comment: I want to learn so i am not taking data for some specific purpose except learning . i have set an input field in template now i am using block for the functionality . i want to send the data collected from input to some table in the database . for example i want to add category name from that input .